# Chrome not downloading PDFs on Marshmallow

Tags: chrome-for-android, pdf, 6.0-marshmallow

I migrated from a Nexus 5 to a Nexus 5X using "Set up nearby device". On the Nexus 5 when I visit turtletrader.com/pdfs/babe-ruth.pdf in Chrome it offers to download the PDF. On the Nexus 5X it doesn't do anything.

Comment: While you have self-answered the question, could you explain some info about data migration from Nexus 5 to 5X? Probably this can give some info why this issue happened.

Comment: I add that I used "Set up nearby device" but that may be a red herring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this by the following:

1. Go to Settings
2. Select Apps
3. Select Chrome
4. Clicking Disable
5. Enabling again

Then when I try to download a PDF it asked for permission to access the folder.

As pointed out in the comments a better fix is:

1. Go to Settings
2. Select Apps
3. Select Chrome
4. Select Permissions
5. Enable Storage permission

Comment: Good to hear that you solved it by yourself. Anyway, I guess the root cause of the problem is with the permission, which alternatively can be fixed by 4) going to **Permissions**, then 5) enable **Storage** permission. But without such hint from re-enabling the app, it'd be almost impossible to know.